# Mongo/meteor how to get the last object?

Tags: meteor

i'll be glad to any help) 
for example, i have a collection with objects:

```
{
    playerId: '',
        name: '',
        link: '',
        seat: '',
        ownNumber: '',
        place: '',
        gameNumber: '',
    }
```

how can i get the objects with the highest number in {gameNumber: } ?

$natural: is don't work

Comment: Is `gameNumber` an integer?

Comment: so, what do you want to do ? finding the last object or finding the object with the highest number ?

Comment: both) actually the object with the highest number in {gameNumber: } is last object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a sort specifier as well as a limit.

```
return YourCollection.find({},{sort:{gameNumber: -1},limit:5})
```

This will return a cursor with the 5 highest gameNumbers, in order from largest to smallest.

Just for your own reference, technically gameNumber is a key, not an object. The entire {...} is a single object.